# Django - access session in signal

Tags: django, session, signals

My application saves data in anonymous users’ sessions. I need to access this data in a signal when the user creates his account. I was thinking about using a post_save signal when a User object is created. The problem is, I do not know how to access the session in the signal.
I thought about three possible solutions:

1. using the SessionStore object (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-out-of-views). The problem is, since I do not have access to the session or the cookies in the signal, I cannot get the session key to retrieve the session

   signals.py file:

   ```py
   @receiver([post_save], sender=User)
   def get_from_session(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):

       s = SessionStore(session_key= ???) # how to access the key?
       data = s.get(‘my_special_session_data’)
       …
   ```
2. modify or wrap the User object, to make the django request an attribute of his, which could be passed with the signal. But I may not implement this solution for the current project, since I have no access to the User object.
3. handling the session data in the view, but this solution is suboptimal since we want to automatize the process.

Any thought? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Django does not the way to do it

But you could use this snippet:

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2179/

Comment: Thanks Goin! This does provide the user, which can be really useful,  but in this specific case I also need the session.

Comment: @Raphael only you have to change 'user' to 'session' in every case